# ASP.NET V5-RC1: Cannot reference class library from web application project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have an issue with ASP.NET V5 RC1 where it won't let me add a reference to a class library (targeting the 4.6 framework) from my web application. When I right click references and select "Add reference" and then select Solution-> Class library, it shows an error that says

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The following projects are not supported as references : 

  - The project XYZ has a target framework that is incompatible or has version higher than the current project and cannot be referenced.
```

Hopefully I'm just doing something silly, but google isn't helping.  I've tried changing the target framework for the class library to no avail. Can anybody tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Look in the project.json of the class library and see what the target frameworks are. Then look at the project.json of the web application and see what the target frameworks are. Then report back here.

Comment: Initially I was using old school class libraries, so they didn't have a project.json. After some googling I get the impression that I need to turn them into "Class Library (Package)" instead... This has got me a little further but now I'm getting errors about "System.Runtime" not being referenced. Quite confused :-/

Comment: I recently moved 23 class libraries targeted at .NET 4.6 to use the new DNX architecture, targeting `net46`. The way I did it was create a new Class Library (Package) for each one under the Web node in the New Project screen. Then I copied all the .cs files into the new project. Then I removed the .NET Core target framework and added references to the appropriate NuGet packages. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I just did something similar.  though I changed all the frameworks of my class libraries to dnx46 and similar to my web app referencing them and they're now building. Quite confused how this all hangs together now. I'm assuming that since I'm now targeting something other than the core framework I wouldn't be able to run this all on linux\mac?

Comment: Correct, can't run on Mac or Linux if you're targeting dnx46. But still, you did the right thing. Once you've verified you got it all working with dnx46 you can add .NET Core back in as a target framework and have it build for  both at the same time. For anything that isn't available in both frameworks, you can either find a different library that is compatible with both, or you can `#if NET46` your way around those issues Just think of getting it to work with dnx46 as the first step, and add in the .NET Core later.